# Go Mock postgresql errors

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, go, pq

As discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560627/6619424), I have written code for checking a unique key violation:

```
if err, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
    if err.Code.Name() == "unique_violation" {
        fail(w, http.StatusBadRequest, 0, "Item already exists")
                    return
        }
}
```

For writing unit-testcases, I need to mock this error. I have written the mock for the error like this:

```
return pq.Error{Code: "unique_violation"}
```

But this does not matches with the code. How do I mock the `pq.Error`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the [Godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#ErrorCode), `ErrorCode is a five-character error code.` `err.Code.Name()` gets the human-friendly version of the error, but the error itself should be represented, and thus constructed, by the error code, which [in this case is 23505](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/error.go#L178).

Comment: So how can I construct the error code? `pq.Error{Code: pq.ErrorCode(23505)}` doesn't seems to be working

Comment: The underlying type is still a `string`, so you should be doing `pq.Error{Code: "23505"}`.

Comment: Could you give any more information? What is `err.Code.Name()` returning?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having issues with this, here is what worked for me. I was going through similar issue years later and this is the code that works.

```
var errCode *pq.Error
errCode = &pq.Error{
        Code: "23505" ,// unique_violation errorcode
    } 

gomock.EXPECT().
 FooBar(gomock.Any()).Times(1).
 Return(foo{}, errCode)
```

[pq.Error](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/v1.10.9/error.go#L25) is a struct defined in the pq package, so you just have to initiate the struct with the custom field you want. This is the ErrorCode field. But this must be declared as a pointer to the Error just as we are asserting in the code.

```
err, ok := err.(*pq.Error)
```

Your endpoint then takes care of the rest by asserting and calling the `Name()` method on the `*pq.Error`. Now you can run your unit tests.